# Pass html tag to angularjs variable from controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this validations which I am trying to do every time user enters a wrong email. And I am handling it via variable in my html like this:

```
 <p class="error"  ng-show="!!user.errorText || form.$submitted">
    {{user.errorText}}
 </p>
```

So far everything is fine as I am replacing the errorText with text values from my controller like this:

```
$scope.user.errorText = "Email is incorrect"
```

Now, I actually wanted to insert a html tag like `<a>` . For example:

```
$scope.user.errorText = "Email is incorrect . <a href='#'>View Examples</a>"
```

But the vaiable `{{user.errorText}}` is always redering it as text. Any help on how can I render both tags and text would be helpful. Also, I can't replace `{{user.errorText}}` in html as it has already been in use for n number of validations and the scenario of using a html tag is rare.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-bind-html` directive to bind html text (it will work also for simple text):

```
<p ng-bind-html="user.errorText"></p>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

If `angular-sanitize.js` is not included in the application, then the following error will show up:

> angular.min.js:1 Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.

In that case, `$sce` service needs to be used like this:

```
$scope.user.errorText = $sce.trustAsHtml("Email is incorrect . <a href='#'>View Examples</a>");
```